# How can I open a .jpg in Photoshop by default (Registry)

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, adobe-photoshop

I'm looking for a way that I can edit the registry to open up .jpg's in Photoshop be default. I guess my questions are one - is this possible? Two - how do you do it? I know you are supposed to provide 'attempts' and why it didnt work but I am too big of a noob and I don't even know where to start. Thanks

Edit - Let me add some clarity. I want this to effect all users for the computer. Plus I need the REGISTRY change... of course I know you can choose a default program... I ultimately want to write a script that will make this change to every computer.

Answer (score 1):

1. Find a .jpg file.
2. Right click said file.
3. Select "Open With" from the context menu.
4. Select "Choose default program" from the context menu.
5. Select Photoshop or browse for the Photoshop application executable.
6. Check the "Always use the selected program to open this kind of file" checkbox.
7. Click the OK button.
8. Done.

Comment: This works with all file association by the way.

Comment: I need the registry change, because I am trying to include this in a script.